# Entity framework insert error

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 class table 
and Category table have 1 record ,for example catID = 2 ... 
and There is no record of the product table

now , When adding a new record to the table Images , 
When I entered CategpryID = 2 , ProductID = 0 ... 
I am getting error  :( 
What do I need ???***

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Images = new List<Image>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

[Table("Categorys")]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Images = new List<Image>();
    }
    public int CategpryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

[Table("Images")]
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }

    public int CategpryID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would be useful to get the exception type and message in your question

Comment: I'd imagine that your `ProductID = 0` is throwing a Foreign Key error. Most likely there won't be a Product with an ID of 0.